# UITextField EditingDidBegin triggered twice on IOS 14.4

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, rx-swift

I have two textfields. I want to open a bottomsheet when the first textfield is tapped. And the other textfield is accepting user input regularly.

This is my trigger when the `produklistrikDropdown` text field with `edittingDidBegin`.

```
produkListrikDropDown.rx.controlEvent(.editingDidBegin)
            .subscribe(onNext:{
                self.dismissKeyboard()
                print("produk Listrik Field did begin")
                self.viewModel.showProdukListrik()
            })
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

And after I choose a product from the bottom sheet it just change the text of the field to the one i choose.

```
viewModel.currentProdukListBehaviorSubject
            .map{$0?.rawValue}
            .subscribe(onNext: { [unowned self] in
                if produkListrikDropDown.text != $0 {
                    produkListrikDropDown.text = $0
                }
            })
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

This is my second textfield configuration. Just a regular textfield receiving input from the user.

```
idPelangganField.rx.text
            .bind(to: viewModel.currentIdPelangganBehaviorSubject)
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

### What Happen

When I tapped the first textfield and choose a product, its acting okay.
But when I tapped the second textfield and tapped back to the first textfield, the edittingDidBegin on the first textfield triggered twice. This doesn't happen on IOS 12.4.

You can clone this repo to reproduce the problem
https://github.com/Bobbyphtr/TextfieldDidEdittingProblem/tree/master

Comment: What function are you putting the code in? Did you know that text fields have an `inputView`? You could probably use that instead and make your code much simpler.

Comment: @DanielT. Thank you for your advice, I will consider using `inputView` for my further implementations. But, even though I used `inputView`, i think they will be triggered twice, as same as the stated problem.

Comment: What function are you putting the code in?

Comment: @DanielT. I put all the code above inside `viewDidLoad` function. If this not the answer you looking for, please elaborate more so I can provide more code needed.

Comment: There's not enough information here to solve the problem, but make sure you only have one view controller instantiated.

Comment: @DanielT. thanks for letting me know, I'm trying to recreate this problem and upload it to github so you can try to find out.

Comment: Hello @DanielT. , I have uploaded a git repo that reproduce this problem. You can take a look from there. Thanks. If there's an issue, let me know.. Thanks for your responses btw :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a better way without sacrificing the use of textfield. Like @Daniel T. said, that we can use a tap gesture recognizer on it. I put a Tag Gesture Recognizer for the UITextField and set it to receive `touch down` events. It eliminates any side effects of the `textFieldShouldBeginEditting(_:)` and also not use any RxSwift to make the call.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are performing side effects in `textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_:)`. The operating system is free to call this function as often as it wants because the only thing the function is for is to find out whether the SDK should allow the text field to begin editing.

Read up on [Command-Query Separation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command%E2%80%93query_separation) (Not just the Wikipedia article. Do an internet search and read other articles about it as well.)

> It states that every method should either be a command that performs
> an action, or a query that returns data to the caller, but not both.
> In other words, asking a question should not change the answer.[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command%E2%80%93query_separation)
> More formally, methods should return a value only if they are
> referentially transparent and hence possess no side effects.

The solution to your problem is to use a UILabel with a tap gesture recognizer on it instead of a text field. Make sure you set the label's `isInteractionEnabled` to true.

---

I found a second problem in your code as well. The Observable returned by `showBottomSheetPicker(selectionList:)` never completes. Make sure you call `observer.onCompleted()` after sending the next event.

Comment: so does this mean that I should avoid overriding the `textFieldShouldBeginEditting` instead because I may cause side effects? Because the function should be considered as a `query` right?

Thank you so much for that useful article, I learn new things now hahaha